# Pusher Laravel Broadcast Leave Room Notification

Tags: laravel, pusher

I am going to post all my methods inside my app just to keep this clear for me to read. Here is the goal. When a user enters a room, a message is added "USER HAS ENTERED THE ROOM" - that works fine. Now, what I want to do is when a user LEAVES a room, I want it to say "USER HAS LEFT THE ROOM" - the notification works, but it is showing the wrong username (it shows the username of the person SEEING the message.

What is it I a missing or not grasping

```
    methods: {
        connect() {
            if (this.currentRoom?.id) {
                let vm = this;
                this.getMessages();
                Echo.join("chat." + this.currentRoom.id)
                    .here(users => {
                        this.sendUserActivityNotification(this.$page.props.user, true)
                        this.users = users
                        this.usersCount = users.length
                    })
                    .joining(user => {
                        this.users.push(user)
                        this.usersCount = this.usersCount+1
                    })
                    .leaving(user => { 
                        this.sendUserActivityNotification(this.$page.props.user, false)
                        this.users = this.users.filter(({id}) => (id !== user.id))
                        this.usersCount = this.usersCount-1
                    })
                    .listen('NewChatMessage', (e) => {
                        vm.getMessages();
                    });
            }
        },
        setRoom(room) {
            this.currentRoom = room;
        },
        getMessages() {
            axios.get('/chat/room/' + this.currentRoom.id + '/messages')
                .then(response => {
                    this.messages = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },
        sendUserActivityNotification(user, joining) {
            const message = `${user.name} has ${joining === true ? 'entered' : 'left'} the room.`
            return axios.post(`/chat/room/${this.currentRoom.id}/notifications`, {message}).then(() => this.getMessages())
            .catch(console.error)
        },
        leaveRoom({id}) {
            this.$store.dispatch(RoomTypes.LEAVE_ROOM, id)
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Laravel Echo, but after reading your code I think on the `leaving` method call, you are passing current user instead of what you are receiving from the event when you call the `sendUserActivityNotification` method.

Your implementation looks like this:

```php
    ...
    .leaving(user => { 
        this.sendUserActivityNotification(this.$page.props.user, false)
        this.users = this.users.filter(({id}) => (id !== user.id))
        this.usersCount = this.usersCount-1
    })
    ....
```

You are passing `this.$page.props.user` to `this.sendUserActivityNotification` method instead of passing `user`.

You must change that call to `this.sendUserActivityNotification(user, false)`